# Rails: Order by two freign referencees

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails model as this:

Stock:

has_one :location

has_one :product

Product:

belongs_to :stock

Location:

belongs_to :stock

In DB Stock has two foreign key columns:

location_id

product_id

When querying stock, I want to order by name column of location and product (location and then product), how to join these three table and sort?

Currently my biggest challenge is how to join (even two tables), I constantly get wrong column name in SQL output, here is an example:

SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = "stocks"."id"

Where it should be:

SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = **"stocks"."location_id"**

I learned that I may be missing some foreign_key attribute in models, but don't know how to add them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you placed the foreign keys in a wrong table http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

'products' and 'locations' tables both should have 'stock_id' for this code to work:

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location
  has_one :product
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stock
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stock
end
```